# Unable to connect to cassandra 4.0 after upgrading the spring-boot to latest 2.6.6 version

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

I am trying to upgrade Spring Boot to 2.6.6 which is using spring core-5.3.18 & spring-beans is 5.3.18. But I am facing some issues with Cassandra connection: codebase is not able to establish the connection with Cassandra.

The Cassandra version that we are using is 4.0.1 and driver dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the error that I am getting on server startup :

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=7be37940): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s2|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)] 

Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:9042
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0()(Unknown Source) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?